# php passing a utf-8 encoded string fails on soapCall

Tags: php, utf-8, soap-client, utf8mb4, smart-quotes

passing a correctly encoded utf-8 string to a php soapCall and it returns that it is not a valid utf_8 character.

> $source = “test”-@– '— " ½ ℗ ↄ⃝ it′s ‘single’
> echo mb_detect_encoding( $source, "auto" ) is UTF-8
>
> hex = E2 80 9C 74 65 73
> 74 E2 80 9D 2D 40 E2 80 93 20 27 E2 80 94 20 22 20 C2 BD 20 20 E2 84
> 97 20 20 E2 86 84 E2 83 9D 20 20 69 74 E2 80 B2 73 20 E2 80 98 73 69
> 6E 67 6C 65 E2 80 99
>
> Error: processSalesOrder interupted because of SOAP-ERROR: Encoding:
> string '\x9c...' is not a valid utf-8 string

returns: �TEST�-@� '� " ½  � ��  IT�S �SINGLE�

added 'encoding' => 'UTF-8' to both the soapClient init options and to the soapCall options.

mariadb Database, table, column are utf8mb4, collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci

php.ini default_charset = "UTF-8"

database connection is set to utf8mb4
html page set to charset=utf8

Displays correctly on webpage.
encoding detect shows UTF-8 right before sending to soapCall, but is rejected by soapCall.

What am I missing?

EDIT:
I also used suggestion from [PHP DOMDocument::save() saves as ASCII instead of UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522323/php-domdocumentsave-saves-as-ascii-instead-of-utf-8) but it didn't help.

> $xmlDomDoc->encoding = 'UTF-8';

I finally resolved the issue changing settings in php.ini for [iconv] and [mbstring] to UTF-8

> iconv.input_encoding = UTF-8
>
> iconv.internal_encoding = UTF-8
>
> iconv.output_encoding = UTF-8
>
> mbstring.internal_encoding = UTF-8
>
> mbstring.http_input = UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

When trying to use utf8/utf8mb4, if you see **Black Diamonds** with question marks,
one of these cases exists:

Case 1 (original bytes were *not* utf8):

- The bytes to be stored are not encoded as utf8.  Fix this.
- The connection (or `SET NAMES`) for the `INSERT` *and* the `SELECT` were not utf8/utf8mb4.  Fix this.
- Also, check that the column in the database is `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4).

Case 2 (original bytes *were* utf8):

- The connection (or `SET NAMES`) for the `SELECT` was not utf8/utf8mb4.  Fix this.
- Also, check that the column in the database is `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4).

Black diamonds occur only when the browser is set to `<meta charset=UTF-8>`